# get available memory in winrt

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to plot a larger amount of data within an metro application and I need to buffer this. To find out how far I can buffer it would be great to know how much memory is still available (to my app), this shouldn't inlclude virtual memory.
Is there any way in a metro app to get this Information? I only found GlobalMemoryStatusEx, but that can only be used in desktop apps

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had to deal with this and got hold of the right people at Microsoft to answer this. Unfortunately the answer was : No you can't do that, except use the restricted calls that you found but using those prevents you from getting certified for publication in the store.

Answer (score 0):

How about just trying to allocate a lot of memory in chunks. When it first fails - add up the sizes of the chunks and either release them or use them for your operations.

Comment: that won't work as this will allocate virtual memory. I wanted to make sure that all data that I load (I do buffering) is available from (non-virtual) memory

Comment: If you keep using all the buffers and make sure there are no delays in allocations you should be able to tell the amount of memory available until you get an exception, though once you get one - your app could also become unstable.